# How can we access the array fields from Avro Schema in the Kafka producer code?

Tags: java, arrays, apache-kafka, avro

I have the below Avro Schema:

```
    `{
      "name": "ABC",
      "type": "record",
      "namespace": "com.schema.avro",
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "str1",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "arrData",
          "type":["null",
          {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "name": "arrData_record",
              "type": "record",
              "fields": [
                {
                  "name": "var1",
                  "type": ["null","string"],
                  "default": null
                },
                {
                  "name": "var2",
                  "type": ["null","int"],
                  "default": null
                }
              ]
            }
          }
          ],
          "default": null
        }
      ]
    }`
```

I used the POM.XML Maven plugin to generate the classes.
Below 2 classes were generated from the plugin-
i)  ABC
ii) arrData_record

I am able to use the field str1 from ABC as below:

```
    ABC abc = ABC.newBuilder()
           .setStr1("random value")
           .build()
```

Similarly, I am also getting an option to use .setArrData().

I want to set the array fields in a similar way using .setVar1() and .setVar2().

How can I use the fields from the Array class and set it similarly? Any sample code would be of great help.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Shivam. What does the generated code look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generated class from the Avro schema could be manipulated like this

```
ABC
    .newBuilder()
    .setArrData(Collections.singletonList(arrData_record
        .newBuilder()
        .setVar1("Var1")
        .setVar2(2)
        .build()))
    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though I accepted Nic's answer and that answer is correct, I used the below code finally as I wanted to add multiple values in Var1 and Var2-

Populated the objects of the arrData_record using below code-

arrData_record a1 = arrData_record.newBuilder()
.setVar1("abc")
.setVar2(1)
.build();

arrData_record a2 = arrData_record.newBuilder()
.setVar1("def")
.setVar2(2)
.build();

Added it into list arrData-

arrData.add(a1);
arrData.add(a2);

Finally added arrData-

ABC abc = ABC.newBuilder()
.setStr1("random value")
.setarrData(arrData)
.build()